# how to store multi dimensional array in sqflite using flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I need to store the multi dimensional array into sqflite db and fetch the same. I can insert single dimensional array to sqflite and fetch. But i am struggling to do for multi dimensional array. Please help me to resolve this.

```
[{
    "Date": "2020-02-17",
    "Data": [{
       "Id": 1
    }, {
        "Id": 2
    }, {
        "Id": 3
    }]
},
 {
    "Date": "2020-02-18",
    "Data": [{
       "Id": 4
    }, {
        "Id": 5
    }, {
        "Id": 6
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your array as JSON and save as string into a database, then after fetching, decode JSON to a regular map.

All you need to do is this

```
import 'dart:convert';

final myArrayJson = jsonEncode(myArray);
final myArrayRegular = jsonDecode(myArrayJson);
```

Comment: how to pass value in insert after decode or encode bcz it want map value instead of string using sqflite package

Comment: you need to assign your string value to a particular column. So in the SQLite table, you'll have a column "younameit" with a string value, containing an encoded array.